# Set the name of the network on a Windows 2012 server without Active Directory

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2012 server that I use for DHCP, DNS and NAT on a network without a Domain Controler, and I don't want to create a Domain.

When my Windows 7 clients connect to it, they Identify the network with the name "Network". Is there any setting on the Windows 2012 server that will allow me to change the name that the clients identify the network with? I want something that is on the Server side and not to manually go and rename it on each client.

I have noticed how low-end devices like access points, modems etc. use their own custom network name that their clients identify their network with, so I am assuming it can't be something too difficult...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use a 2012 server for DHCP, DNS, and NAT(?) and not create a domain?  Why not skip the licensing and use a Linux server instead?

Comment: why do you care what the network name is?  Users don't need to see it or use it mostly.

Comment: I'm planning to use it for more than this. I don't need the domain because all the clients are guests so there's no need for remote management.

Comment: And this is the exact reason why I care about the name. I would rather have visitors when they join to see a name that makes sense to them than seeing a generic one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean the network name in the "network and sharing center"?

This is determined by NLA (network location awareness).

By design it checks a reg key first:

> HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group
>   Policy\History\NetworkName

and if the connection specific DNS Name that the NIC has matches that value then the machine contacts a DC and if successful you get the domain profile and name.

Otherwise, like in your case, it ends up giving you the default (public) until the Win 7 machines choose that it is a private/work network and then give it a name if they want individually or leave it as "Network".

There's not a setting on the Win 2012 server that can be set through DHCP that I'm aware of, but you can use either a login script or batch file to modify the registries on each Win7 machine if you want.

The keys are found here:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles

The problem being, if these clients have been on multiple networks you'll need to determine which network is yours to modify the proper profile in this registry section.

Look in that key in the registry of a few client machines and see if the GUIDs match up for your "Network".  If they do, you are golden for creating the script.  If they don't, then you'll have to either get fancy with your script or go about this the manual way.

**Manual way**:

In the "network and sharing center" in control panel, click on the active network icon, then change the name.  You can change the icon too if you feel like it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer TheCleaner.

Running scripts on the clients computers is not a good option for my scenario. So it seems that the only way to get the name is by getting the NLA to comunicate with a DC, which means I have to settup a DC...